# How to import a specific Key with its values in a csv file using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, export-to-csv

In my program, the user will enter a country name and my code will first whether or not the country name exists in the dictionary. If it exists, the code has to print the country name and its associated values in a csv file. However, I am unable to do the csv part. I have presented the dictionary and relevant code for this issue. Kindly let me know what the issue is.

```
import string
import re
import csv

data = {
    "Pakistan": (0.57, 0.05, 0.79),
    "India": (0.47, 0.12, 0.54),
    "Bangladesh": (0.49, 0.17, 0.81)
    }
csv_columns = ['Country Name','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010']
csv_file = "Emissions_subset.csv"

con_name = input("Write up to three comma-separated countries for which you want to extract data: ")
count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', con_name))
if count == 1:
    con_check1 = con_name.split()[0]
    if con_check1.lower() in map(str.lower, data.keys()):
        with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(list(data.keys()).index(con_check1))
        print("Data successfully extracted for countries {} saved into file Emissions_subset.csv".format(con_check1.capitalize()))
```

Comment: what error are you getting?  what doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'